# How to split a string into several lines while keeping a prefix?

Tags: string, shell, awk, split

I would like to split several lines like the following using CLI tools like `awk`.

```
prefix11 prefix12 prefix13 key11 value11 key12 value12
prefix21 prefix22 prefix23 key21 value21 key22 vaule22 key23 value23
prefix31 prefix32 prefix33 key31 value31
```

Each line has a fixed number of prefixes (separated by a space) followed by key value pairs. The result should have the prefixes in every line, but with only one key value pair:

```
prefix11 prefix12 prefix13 key11 value11
prefix11 prefix12 prefix13 key12 value12
prefix21 prefix22 prefix23 key21 value21
prefix21 prefix22 prefix23 key22 value12
prefix21 prefix22 prefix23 key23 value23
prefix31 prefix32 prefix33 key31 value31
```

I know how to split the string with `awk`, but I'm struggling with the prefixes and with the fact that the number of key value pairs is not fixed.

How can the intended result be achieved with Unix/Linux CLI commands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be a way:

```
awk '{a=$1 OFS $2 OFS $3; for (i=4; i<NF; i+=2) print a,$i,$(i+1); a=""}' file
```

#### Explanation

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS=" "}` is optional.
- `a=$1 OFS $2 OFS $3` store the three first values in the `a` variable. The `OFS` is used so that you can specifiy another Output Field Separator in the `BEGIN{}` block and will apply to everything your print.
- `for (i=4; i<NF; i+=2) print a,$i,$(i+1)` print in blocks of two: the three initial values + a pair of key-value values.
- `a=""` empty the variable.

#### Checking

```
$ awk '{a=$1 OFS $2 OFS $3; for (i=4; i<NF; i+=2) print a,$i,$(i+1); a=""}' test
prefix11 prefix12 prefix13 key11 value11
prefix11 prefix12 prefix13 key12 value12
prefix21 prefix22 prefix23 key21 value21
prefix21 prefix22 prefix23 key22 vaule22
prefix21 prefix22 prefix23 key23 value23
prefix31 prefix32 prefix33 key31 value31
```

Comment: +1 but use OFS to create "a". also, no need for a=""

Comment: Fair enough, just updated. Also I saw that `a=$1 OFS $2 OFS $3` is also possible, so wrote it this way for readability sake.

Answer (score 1):

It is straightforward script, not sure why need save in var `a` first and then clean it.

```
awk '{for (i=4;i<=NF;i+=2) print $1,$2,$3,$i,$(i+1)}' file
```